# CRE Loaded error after installation success?

Tags: e-commerce

this question is directed to a CRE Loaded expert, 
I have Installed CRE Loaded successfully but when I am trying to reach my Catalog Page I have the following error:

```
(Unable to connect to database server!)
and Admin page resulted in the following error (Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user ' site_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/site/public_html/creloaded/admin/i… on line 19
Unable to connect to database server!)
```

I have unchecked Enable SSL dose this affect CRE Loaded functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the database connection. There is an issue with the installer, it gave a false positive on the connection check, and allowed you to proceed even though the database connection failed.

This has been resolved in the current 6.5.1 release.